# AFNetworking and NSURLRequest timeout hang/beachball

Tags: afnetworking

UPDATE #3: Here is a link to the original github issue on this and a potential solution that we are trying now...updating to AFNetworking 1.3.0

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1054

---

UPDATE #2: Once we get to this state where things deadlock, it seems it may be dying in the [AFHTTPClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:] method. Peppered it with NSLogs and sent to user with the problem to see what it shows.

---

UPDATE #1: Here is a recent spin report of it right when it happened - this seems to point to some interesting things - anyone have any thoughts on this?

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2053112/myapp_AFNetworking.spin

Adding a reference to github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/907 since the proximity of the code is very close.

Note also that the watchdog block was able to detect and cancel the (about to fail) operation but alas, even though it was cancelled, the damage had already been done and the app deadlocks.

---

ORIGINAL POST:

I have the following situation that I wanted to outline to see if anyone else had ever seen anything like it.

I'm using AFNetworking in a UIElement (menubar item only) MacOSX application that enumerates and uses file system events to monitor directories for files that are then processed and uploaded to a server. The files are stored in a Core Data store and marked for needing to be uploaded, etc.

Using GCD I have 3 network operations that are performed round-robin - each triggers the next and the last triggers the process again - so only one is ever processing at once. There is 1-2 seconds of delay between each operation. One of these operations POSTs to see if the file should be uploaded. The next PUTs the file if needed. The last DELETEs any files that are marked for deletion. The PUT is my problem.

The (class) method that handles the PUT is called on a newly created dispatch queue explicitly used for it via:

```
dispatch_queue_t q_put = dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp.put", NULL);
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_SEC * kPause), q_put, ^(void){
     @autoreleasepool {
          PUTfiles(completionBlock);
     }
});
dispatch_release(q_put);
```

The method then creates an NSOperationQueue and an NSBlockOperation, adds it to the queue and lets it go. The NSBlockOperation is where all the work is. Basically this block gets a file url from Core Data and then creates the PUT (via AFNetworking) and queues it for upload. In detail, I'm creating an NSURLRequest as a PUT with the file attached. An AFHTTPRequestOperation is then created and enqueueHTTPRequestOperation enqueues it.

Up to this point everything is good. The process actually runs fine for the most part. The problem comes in when NSURLRequest times out. After 60 seconds, if NSURLRequest times out AFNetworking tries to call the failure block in the AFHTTPRequestOperation but instead the app "beach balls" - other file processes in my app continue to run but AFNetworking is deadlocked - possibly waiting on a semaphore of sorts. Here is a sample call stack:

```
  Thread 0x958      DispatchQueue 1          priority 47       
  31 ??? (My App + 4980) [0x106b5b374]
31 NSApplicationMain + 869 (AppKit) [0x7fff8630fc06]
  31 -[NSApplication run] + 517 (AppKit) [0x7fff8636b1d3]
    31 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128 (AppKit) [0x7fff86373e22]
      31 _DPSNextEvent + 685 (AppKit) [0x7fff86374563]
        31 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62 (HIToolbox) [0x7fff90109ae3]
          31 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 356 (HIToolbox) [0x7fff90109c52]
            31 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 209 (HIToolbox) [0x7fff90109eb4]
              31 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290 (CoreFoundation) [0x7fff8de710e2]
                31 __CFRunLoopRun + 789 (CoreFoundation) [0x7fff8de717f5]
                  31 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 245 (CoreFoundation) [0x7fff8de4e455]
                    31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17 (CoreFoundation) [0x7fff8de4eb31]
                      31 _cfstream_shared_signalEventSync + 640 (CoreFoundation) [0x7fff8ded3e00]
                        31 _signalEventSync + 108 (CoreFoundation) [0x7fff8de9503c]
                          31 ??? (My App + 162305) [0x106b81a01]
                            31 CFWriteStreamWrite + 380 (CoreFoundation) [0x7fff8de6f56c]
                              31 boundPairWrite + 586 (CoreFoundation) [0x7fff8df3f7ea]
                                31 _CFStreamSignalEvent + 615 (CoreFoundation) [0x7fff8de94df7]
                                  31 _cfstream_solo_signalEventSync + 100 (CoreFoundation) [0x7fff8de94fc4]
                                    31 _signalEventSync + 108 (CoreFoundation) [0x7fff8de9503c]
                                      31 ??? (My App + 162305) [0x106b81a01]
                                        31 CFWriteStreamWrite + 380 (CoreFoundation) [0x7fff8de6f56c]
                                          31 boundPairWrite + 149 (CoreFoundation) [0x7fff8df3f635]
                                            31 __psynch_mutexwait + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib) [0x7fff8a758122]
                                             *31 psynch_mtxcontinue + 0 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80005b34e0]
```

NOTE: This only happens on some machines - running Mountain Lion - 5% of users been reported but we've only been able to fully reproduce and test on one particular machine. Not to mention it can take hours for the problem to exhibit naturally.

NOTE ALSO: It usually exhibits itself to the user as a spinning beach ball when they hover over the menubar NSStatusItem for my app.

Note that even if I pass in a specific fallback queue (for both success and failure) the same problem seems to occur - but only on (at least one) machine. Other machines work absolutely fine. Here is a recent crash where it actually crashed while calling the success block on the fallback queue - it had been running for 8+ hours when this occurred and called the success block hundreds of times successfully before this:

```
Crashed Thread:  10  Dispatch queue: com.myapp.put.success.queue

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000008

VM Regions Near 0x8:
Thread 10 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.myapp.put.success.queue
0   libdispatch.dylib                  0x00007fff89920e1c _dispatch_retain + 0
1   libdispatch.dylib                  0x00007fff89923871 dispatch_source_cancel + 17
2   com.mydomain.myapp                 0x0000000109154722 __PUTfiles_block_invoke281 + 98
3   com.mydomain.myapp                 0x000000010916b32c __64-[AFJSONRequestOperation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:]_block_invoke79 + 44
4   libdispatch.dylib                  0x00007fff89923f01 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
5   libdispatch.dylib                  0x00007fff899200b6 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
6   libdispatch.dylib                  0x00007fff8992147f _dispatch_queue_drain + 235
7   libdispatch.dylib                  0x00007fff899212f1 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 52
8   libdispatch.dylib                  0x00007fff899211c3 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 249
9   libsystem_c.dylib                  0x00007fff8705cd0b _pthread_wqthread + 404
10  libsystem_c.dylib                  0x00007fff870471d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x1c711b723ffeb051  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x00007faa010eb040  rdx: 0x00000000a1a1a1a1
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x00007faa010eb000  rbp: 0x000000010aa5ad20  rsp: 0x000000010aa5ad08
   r8: 0x00007faa0287b970   r9: 0x0000000064cb29bf  r10: 0x00007faa0289a570  r11: 0x000000006744ce88
  r12: 0x0000000000010001  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x00007faa01842540  r15: 0x00007faa01842574
  rip: 0x00007fff89920e1c  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x0000000000000008
Logical CPU: 0
```

Quitting the app and restarting it helps reset things. Note this only happens when NSURLRequest times out (60 seconds) - other failures where the server actually responds are handled fine and no hang occurs. The process continues and tries again properly.

I'm currently trying a watchdog block that gets called 45 seconds after a PUT begins and cancels the operation if it hasn't completed yet. When I set this to .25 seconds it works fine on the machine in question - cancels the operation and picks up to try again. I'm hopeful that this solves the problem but having fought this bug for 2 weeks trying various things on this users machines (build after build with log statements to try to track things down) I'm not holding my breath. Mind you, since it also crashed when calling the success block above I'm a bit concerned now that that is even the right approach - the success crash was new just this morning - it had always been a failure crash before.

Thoughts? Thanks in advance!